# HR rep may have asked me to falsify date on I-9

Tags: documentation

I started a new job several months ago. The company did not give me the I-9 to complete until my third day of employment. One section of the document is supposed to be filled out on or before the first day of employment, but I was told it wouldn't be an issue. I filled out the form and dated it accurately.

Several months later, someone fairly high up the HR ladder sends me an email asking me to re-sign and resubmit the form *with my first day of employment as the date of signature.*

I'm not comfortable doing this. It's a legal document and it seems to me they're asking for me to falsify it (possibly to avoid fines for a mistake *they* made, namely failing to give me the document on time.)

I forwarded the email to my immediate HR rep and stated (diplomatically) that I wasn't comfortable doing this. Are there any other steps I should take?

Comment: Never participate in fraud, be prepared to move on, however

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I forwarded the email to my immediate HR rep and stated
>   (diplomatically) that I wasn't comfortable doing this. Are there any
>   other steps I should take?

You can offer to sign a note, crafted by HR, attesting that you were eligible to work on the date you were hired. You would sign it and date it with the current date, not backdated.

HR could then attach the note to the original I9. That would likely satisfy any audit they might encounter.

If they agree, read the note they craft very carefully. Don't sign it unless you agree with everything it says. Feel free to propose alternative language as necessary.

Answer (score 3):

While I get your caution in this situation, I think your **over reacting** here.

My thought is that you were eligible to work and would have completed the form on your first day of employment, but the form that they **need** to have you fill out was *somehow missed in the onboarding process*.

As the comments to the question state, you cannot be forced to do this, but they may ask you to leave or decide your services are no longer necessary to protect themselves.  (*this is a bit of a reach I know, but a possibility non the less*)

Remember, HR's true function **is** to protect the company.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99620/discussion-on-answer-by-mister-positive-hr-rep-may-have-asked-me-to-falsify-date).